# Linux grep command for words beginning with ? character

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I'm struggling a bit with a `grep` command in an assignment.

I need to find every word starting with an 'a' in a document and then have word count determine how many that is. Since some words start with large letters I've done a `tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'`. I can easily get `grep` to find all the 'a' letters in the document and also lines starting with an 'a'. But for some reason I can't get it grep words that start with an 'a'.

Hope you can help me.

---

THX everybody this helped me out a lot

It is quite hard to understand Linux IMO but I'll get there eventually.

Again thx for all the help much appreciated.

Comment: Using GNU grep, does `grep -c '\b[Aa]'` get you the result you want?

Comment: Guess with \b you also grep the word if the a is at the end

Comment: @terence that would be `[Aa]\b`, surely?

Comment: @TomFenech You are right!

Comment: @terence yeah you can use those weird word boundaries too but I don't think they do anything useful here, except on some specific older versions of GNU grep that might not understand `\b`.

Comment: I won't be able to compare notes with my teammates before tomorrow, but from what I can see it yields a much more acceptable result. Only thing is that we created a test file where we could see if our code would display the correct answer because we only made a couple of words with the starting letter a and your code yields a result of 1 on that but we have 3 words with a in it although that is separated with , 

I'll show an example of our file here 
We made four lines like this 
Firstname, lastname, department, initials

But I think the error is due to us writing something wrong in test.txt

Comment: @sypherian 3 words that have "a" in them or 3 that start with "a"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding counting option to Martins script.

```
grep -Eowc "[Aa]\w+"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, combining `-c` with `-o` is not portable -- in particular, GNU `grep` has a long-standing bug which is still not fixed: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?33080

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do

```
grep -Eow "[Aa]\w+" | wc -l
```

Which says find all words (`-w`) that begin with an "a" (`[Aa]`) and is followed by 1 or more word characters (`\w+`).

The `-o` options prints only matched output.

Example

```
echo " Aest test aest test" | grep -Eow "[Aa]\w+" | wc -l  # returns 2
```

Comment: I think that answers the question in the title, but not in the body of the question

Comment: Thank you this gives me the desired result much appreciated :-D

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNU awk, then change the record separator to any spaces (so each word becomes a record) and keep a count:

```
awk -v RS='\\s+' '/^[Aa]/ { ++count } END { print count + 0 }' file
```

The `+ 0` just makes the output a bit more clear in case there are no matches (it prints `0`, rather than an empty string). More correct would be `if (NR) print count + 0` so no input => no output but you might consider than overkill.

On other versions of awk, you could just loop through each word on the line manually:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /^[Aa]/) ++count } END { print count + 0 }' file
```

Comment: As @sypherian's comment points out, this will print the number of lines that contain at least one word that begins with an "a", but not the number of words themselves